# How can I count records only once within a time range?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table with statistical data.

I'm trying to count the records grouped by a version, the problem is that the records have another criteria (ref) and should counted only once (per ref).

stats sample data to illustrate the issue:

```
id stat_date  ref version
-------------------------
1  2012-01-25   1  A
2  2012-01-25   2  B
3  2012-01-25   3  A
4  2012-01-26   8  B
5  2012-01-26   2  B
6  2012-01-26   3  B  <-- version has been updated for ref=3
```

Simple counting would return

```
SELECT COUNT(*),version FROM stat GROUP BY version

1,A
5,B
```

The problem here is that only the last record with ref=3 (id=6) should be counted and (id=3) has to be ignored.
So the question is, how can I filter row (id=3) from the query?

I can't figure out what I should insert as condition in the subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(*),version FROM stats
WHERE  stat_date BETWEEN "2012-01-25"  AND "2012-01-26" 
AND id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM stats WHERE <condition>)
GROUP BY 2
```

The expected result would be:

```
1,A (since id=3 is ignored)
3,B (since the first id=2 is ignored and only id=5 is taken into account)
```

Comment: @Jaitsu because he's using count(*) on column 1 and grouping by column 2

Comment: @Jaitsu It means the second argument in the columns list (version).

Comment: @stacker, learn something new everyday!

Comment: You should also ignore the duplicate ref=2 for version=B...

Comment: @gbn Yes, I'm wasn't carfully enough as I choosed the example scenarion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),version 
FROM stats s1
WHERE stat_date BETWEEN "2012-01-25"  AND "2012-01-26" AND
      not exists (SELECT null 
                  FROM stats s2 
                  WHERE s1.ref = s2.ref and s2.id>s1.id)
GROUP BY version
```

EDIT: Not guaranteed to always work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),version from
(select * from
 (select * from stats 
  where stat_date BETWEEN "2012-01-25"  AND "2012-01-26" 
  order by ref, id desc) s0
 group by ref) s1
group by version
```

Comment: Returns the same results as my COUNT(DISTINCT). It makes no difference what row is actually counted...

Comment: @gbn: With the data previously supplied, yes, but with record ID 3 as version A, then ref 3 would be counted against only version B in my query, while it would be counted against versions A and B in your query.

Comment: @MarkBannister Thank you for the clever statements ++1

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter which row you ignore. All you want is to count ref once.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ref),version FROM stat GROUP BY version
```

Edit:

Your example should also count the 2 rows where ref = 2 once as well according to your logic.

This answers satisfies the questions as posed even if it doesn't solve your unknown real problem

Comment: Thanks, unfourtunatly I forget to mention that I need to count the latest one (I simpified the example). Would there also a solution for that?

Comment: @stacker: well, post your *real* problem then. I answered exactly what you asked

Comment: Sorry at least I tried to imply this by saying "(id=6) should be counted and (id=3) has to be ignored"

Comment: @stacker: that statement has no meaning in set logic for a COUNT. All that matters is that ref=3 is counted once...

Comment: Oh, of course you're right, the real problem is that the records represent devices and their version can be updated, so that I'm only interested in the last records of any ref. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @stacker: that doesn't matter: "last record" has no meaning inside a COUNT. Explain *why* my answer doesn't work for you and update the question as I asked above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7098/discussion-between-stacker-and-gbn)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*),version FROM stats
   WHERE  stat_date BETWEEN "2012-01-25"  AND "2012-01-26" 
       AND id = (SELECT MAX(s.id) FROM stats s WHERE s.id = id)
   GROUP BY version
   ORDER BY stat_date
```

Comment: Sorry, but this returned only one row

Comment: how about changing the `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY id, version`